# why can't I connect to server?

Tags: python, sockets

so I have just started learning network programming and I don't understand why does a connection between the client and the server is constantly denied.

```
import socket
my_socket = socket.socket()
my_socket.connect(("127.0.0.1", 8820))
```

that is the error I get:

```
ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Can you check if anything is running on this port ? I have django application running on 8000 port and if i try to run the above code snippet with 8000 it is connected successfully.

Comment: how do I do that? @DeepakTripathi

Comment: `sudo netstat -nlp | grep :8820` using this command you will get to know if something is running on 8820 port or not , If you find something running then the above code will run fine.

Comment: The code you posted is acting as a client. You need a server to go with that. Where is your server?

Comment: my server is my computer. that why I use 127.0.0.1 ip address @quamrana

Comment: my command promt doesn't recognize 'sudo' @DeepakTripathi

Comment: Which OS are you using ?

Comment: I use windows OS

Comment: Yes, your computer is 127.0.0.1, but you are connecting to port 8820. Which server is on that port?

Comment: actually I am very new to this, I don't really know... I'm learning from a book. According to the book it should work @quamrana

Comment: @coolness A client program connects to a server program. Where is the server program?

Answer (score 2):

A client program connects to a server program. A server program is a program which listens to a particular port and a client program connects to that port.

Your program tries to connect to your own computer, port 8820. If there isn't a program running on your computer which is listening to port 8820, there is nothing to connect to so you get a connection refused error.

"Connection refused" specifically means that your computer *was* able to access IP address 127.0.0.1, but at that IP address, there was no program listening to port 8820.

Comment: thank you @user253751 but how can I make sure I have a program listening to port 8820?

Comment: @coolness you can write a server using listen/accept on a socket, you can install one of many server programs you can install on your computer (notice they all do different things! people connect to servers for *reasons* and not just because. they expect the server to do something) or you can connect to some server on the internet (I am not sure if `"towel.blinkenlights.nl",23` still exists. There is always `"www.google.com",80` but it won't send you anything unless you send it a request first)